# Angular 5 Form validation for optional fields

Tags: angular, validation, textfield

Ok, so I am very new to Angular(I am using Angular 5).  I am trying implement form validation 
such that I have two input fields where:
    -   A user must use one or both fields before submitting the form.
    -   Both fields must adhere to the pattern \w{10}
    -   until validation criteria has been met, the submit button must remain disabled
    -   There needs to be a message underneath each field describing malformed input as
        happens.

I have managed to get something working with regard to the pattern matching and submit button disabled....but I am having a hard time figuring out to provide functionality such that
a user opting to only fill out one field and having the submit button enabled...I can only seem to get it to work when both fields are being used.

```
<!--my view code/mark up.... -->


<div>
  <h3>Angular  Template Form validation </h3>
  <form #userlogin = "ngForm" (ngSubmit) = "onClickSubmit(userlogin.value)" novalidate >
    <p>Is "userlogin" valid? {{userlogin.valid}}</p>
    <input type = "text" name = "emailId" placeholder = "emailId" ngModel required   pattern = "\w+\@\w+\.\w+" />
    <br/>
    <input type = "password" name = "passwd" placeholder = "passwd" ngModel   pattern ="\w{10}"/>
    <br/>
    <input type = "submit"  [disabled] = "!userlogin.valid"  value = "submit">
 </form>
</div>


import { Component, OnInit ,ANALYZE_FOR_ENTRY_COMPONENTS } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl,FormArray,NgForm, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
import {Report} from './report.model';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

      constructor() {}

      ngOnInit() {
        this.report = new Report() ;
        this.isDisabled = false ;
      }


     onClickSubmit(data) {
        let email = data.emailId ;
        let passwd = data.passwd ;
        email = email.trim() ;
        passwd = passwd.trim() ;
        console.log(email);
        this.emailFlag = this.regexpEmail.test(email);
        // alert('Entered Email id : ' + this.emailFlag);
        alert('Email -> ' + email + ': ' + 'passwd :' + passwd );

      }

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated !!!  Thanks!!!!

Comment: Sounds like what you want is to use FormGroup and have a validator on the group as a whole.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below given code:

Template:

```
<div>
  <h3>Angular  Template Form validation </h3>
  <form #userlogin = "ngForm" (ngSubmit) = "onClickSubmit(userlogin.value)" novalidate >
    <p>Is "userlogin" valid? {{userlogin.valid}}</p>
    <input type = "text" name = "emailId" placeholder = "emailId" [(ngModel)]="emailid"  pattern = "\w+\@\w+\.\w+" />
    <br/>
    <input type = "password" name = "passwd" placeholder = "passwd" [(ngModel)]="pwd"  pattern ="\w{10}"/>
    <br/>
    <input type = "submit"  [disabled] = "(!emailid && !pwd) || !userlogin.valid"  value = "submit">
 </form>
</div>
```

Component-

```
import { Component, OnInit ,ANALYZE_FOR_ENTRY_COMPONENTS } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl,FormArray,NgForm, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
import {Report} from './report.model';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  emailid;
  pwd;
      constructor() {}

      ngOnInit() {
        this.report = new Report() ;
        this.isDisabled = false ;
      }

     onClickSubmit(data) {
        let email = data.emailId ;
        let passwd = data.passwd ;
        email = email.trim() ;
        passwd = passwd.trim() ;
        console.log(email);
        this.emailFlag = this.regexpEmail.test(email);
        // alert('Entered Email id : ' + this.emailFlag);
        alert('Email -> ' + email + ': ' + 'passwd :' + passwd );

      }

}
```